# PHP doesn't show MySQL query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a web page with MySQL database. I created a lot of PHP scripts with MySQL querys in this project and all of them working fine. But when I try to run this query on PHP

```
$qry = mysqli_query($baglanti,"SELECT tedavi_adi
        FROM tedaviler
        INNER JOIN hastane_tedaviler
        ON tedaviler.tedavi_id=hastane_tedaviler.tedavi_id
        WHERE hastane_tedaviler.hastane_id=2
        ORDER BY tedaviler.tedavi_adi ASC") or die("ERROR");

$treatments = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    $treatments[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($treatments);
```

It is not giving any error but it is returning empty.

When I move `json_encode($treatments)` code to the `while` loop, it is giving first 2 items like this `[x]`, `[x,y]` in a 6 elements array and giving first 6 elements in 10 elements array.

Query is working fine on MySQL server but not working on PHP. I couldn't figure out.
[image: Tables]

Solved : The problem is Turkish Alphabet Characters coming from server when I change them to English Characters it is worked.

Comment: var_dump your $qry (`var_dumb($qry)`) to check the values retrieved from the db

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*first 2 items ... in a 6 elements array and first 6 elements in 10 elements array*".  Please elaborate?

Comment: Result of query is 6 row but it is showing first two items like this [x],[{x,y}] when I move json_encode to while loop

Comment: @Astro it gives
 `object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null`

Comment: 'num_rows=> null' means how do you get a value when you move `json_encode($treatments)` to the while loop? @SuatKarabacak

Comment: @Astro actually I don't now I added some pictures to question

Comment: Your query in phpmyadmin has `WHERE hastane_tedaviler.hastane_id=2` and in your code it is `WHERE hastane_tedaviler.hastane_id=3`.
Also - turn on error reporting ( `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ) to see what happens - i guess at third row there is a problem with encoding?

Comment: @Kleskowy yes IDs different but it doesn't matter it is same when I change it. It is acctually a dynamic ID but I put just a number in there. `error_reporting(E_ALL)` not showing anything

Comment: You need to show us more code and table structure with some data.

Comment: @user1551066 I added tables too.

Comment: Can you echo in the loop this : echo $row['tedavi_adi']; and see what it outputs?

Comment: @user1551066 it is showing the same thing that I mentioned in question [{'Dahiliye'}],[{'Dahiliye','Diş'}]

Comment: Why do they have {}? Did you echo or var_dump them  $row['tedavi_adi'] in the loop?

Comment: Yes it is gave this `string 'Dahiliye' (length=8)
string 'Di?' (length=3)
string 'G�z' (length=3)
string 'Onkoloji' (length=8)
string 'Sa� ekimi' (length=9)` @user1551066

Comment: So it returns values correctly and it is not empty as you said. What's the problem?

Comment: yes it is returing value correctly there is no problem in there but `echo json_encode($treatments)` doesn't work it is showing result just with `var_dump` @user1551066

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the json_encode function can't correctly parse the array.

Try to output all fields (*) and see if json_encode works properly.

```
$qry = mysqli_query($baglanti,"SELECT *
        FROM tedaviler
        INNER JOIN hastane_tedaviler
        ON tedaviler.tedavi_id=hastane_tedaviler.tedavi_id
        WHERE hastane_tedaviler.hastane_id=2
        ORDER BY tedaviler.tedavi_adi ASC") or die("ERROR");

$treatments = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    $treatments[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($treatments);
```

If it does work properly then the problem is that you trying to output only one field which is incorrect.

Comment: Problems is not that ... I found the problem people, it is because of Turkish Alphabet characters it is confusing json_encode. I change all special characters to English version and it is worked ...

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
//$treatments = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($qry))$treatments[] = $row[0];

echo json_encode($treatments);
```

edited - should have been `$row[0]` instead of `$row`

edit II -
if your sql is returning results in phpmyadmin, it should work.
try this;

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(...);
$sql = "SELECT tedavi_adi
        FROM tedaviler
        INNER JOIN hastane_tedaviler
        ON tedaviler.tedavi_id=hastane_tedaviler.tedavi_id
        WHERE hastane_tedaviler.hastane_id=2
        ORDER BY tedaviler.tedavi_adi ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = $conn->affected_rows;
echo $count;
```

if $count is greater than 0 then your query is working else you have an error in sql

---

i had a problem once transporting array to js. for some reason it was treating it like an object. this is how i solved it, may not be the best method, but it worked for me;

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($qry))$treatments[] = $row[0];
$n=0;
$tmp='{';
foreach($treatments as $index=>$value)
    {
        $tmp .= $index.':"'.$value.'"';
        $n++;
        if($n<count($treatments))$tmp .= ', ';
    }
    $tmp .= '}';
echo $tmp;
```